# How can event-driven architecture be applied to this example?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, rabbitmq, microservices, event-driven

I am unsure how to make use of event-driven architecture in real-world scenarios. Let's say there is a route planning platform consisting of the following back-end services:

- user-service (manages user data and roles)
- map-data-service (roads & addresses, only modified by admins)
- planning-tasks-service
  (accepts new route planning tasks, keeps track of background tasks, stores results)

The public website will usually request data from all 3 of those services. map-data-service needs information about user-roles on a data change request. planning-tasks-service needs information about users, as well as about map-data to validate new tasks.

Right now those services would just make a sync request to each other to get the needed data. What would be the best way to translate this basic structure into an event-driven architecture? Can dependencies be reduced by making use of events? How will the public website get the needed data?

Comment: Redesign your microservice boundaries (i.e. you domains) by event storming the process. This will give you your event model then your microservices boundaries will be obvious.

Comment: That's an interesting read, thanks! However, I would really be interested in a concrete possible solution of EDA for a system like this, especially for the messaging happening to update map-data and create new tasks.

Comment: The best way to do this is to divide your microservices by your domain also understand the consistency and relationship between two entities. Kafka is for asynchronous communication.By using kafka you can loosely couple the system but it depends on each other. For public endpoint data, you still need one endpoint which gets consolidated data

Comment: I think you risk putting the solution before the problem.  Would event-driven architecture help in this scenario?  Maybe, but there are others that might be better.  If you walk around with a hammer, everything will look like a nail.

Comment: @Vaibs I am not sure how you could better divide the microservices than user/map-data/routing. As for asynchronous communication: I don't think it makes any sense to map a req/res call on to 2 kafka topics, it will only increase complexity without reducing dependencies. However, I also don't see a more natural way to utilize events to query for user-authorization for a map-data-update.

Comment: @alexander I have a similar use case, wondering how did you go about solving this. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cosmin is 100% correct in that you need something to do some orchestration.

One approach to take, if you have a client that needs data from multiple services, is the Experience API approach.

Clients call the experience API, which performs the orchestration - pulling data from different sources and providing it back to the client.  The design of the experience API is heavily, and deliberately, biased towards what the client needs.

Based on the details you've said so far, I can't see anything that cries out for event-based architecture.  The communication between the client and ExpAPI can be a mix of sync and async, as can the ExpAPI to [Services] communication.

And for what it's worth, putting all of that on API gateway is not a bad idea, in that they are designed to host API's and therefore provide the desirable controls and observability for managing them.

**Update based on OP Comment**

> I was really interested in how an event-driven architecture could
> reduce dependencies between my microservices, as it is often stated

Having components (or systems) talk via events is sort-of the asynchronous equivalent of Inversion of Control, in that the event consumers are not tightly-coupled to the thing that emits the events.  That's how the dependencies are reduced.

One thing you could do would be to do a little side-project just as a learning exercise - take a snapshot of your code and do a rough-n-ready conversion to event-based and just see how that went - not so much as an attempt to event-a-cise your solution but to see what putting events into a real-world solution looks like.  If you have the time, of course.

Comment: Great answer, Adrian!

Comment: I understand that there needs to be an API Gateway in some form in front of the microservices. But I was really interested in how an event-driven architecture could reduce dependencies between my microservices, as it is often stated. From what I understood from the given answers, is that *EDA does not provide many advantages for basic web applications* like in the example. It is better to stick to a traditional approach, but maybe move some logic/dependencies to an orchestrating gateway.

Answer (score 3):

The missing piece in your architecture is the [API Gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html), which should be the only entry-point in your system, used by the public website directly.

The API Gateway would play the role of an orchestrator, which decides to which services to route the request, and also it assembles the final response needed by the frontend.

For scalability purposes, the communication between the API Gateway and individual microservices should be done asynchronously through an event-bus (or message queue).

However, the most important step in creating a scalable event-driven architecture which leverages microservices, is to properly define the bounded contexts of your system and understand the boundaries of each functionality.

More details about this architecture can be found [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

Comment: I strongly disagree with API GWs acting like ESBs, they become a single point of failure/integration.

Comment: True, that's one of the downsides of this approach (alongside others mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation)) but we can't miss the benefits of bringing consistency, minimising the 1:1 communication between individual microservices, improving traceability and debuggability. In the end, as any other engineering decision, it depends on how you want to balance the tradeoffs so that it maps better on your use-cases.

Comment: To have an API Gateway is a good practice, but my question was really about the event-driven aspect. You mention async messaging. How would that work if an admin uses the website to modify map-data? Will map-data-service publish an i-need-info-about-this-user-uwu-event and then wait for a response, all while the request from the website is being handled? Will the Gateway also publish events?

Comment: Yes, the gateway will also publish events, and the microservices communicate only through events. If you have a use-case where request/response is more suited, then you should use that, as Adrian mentioned. It doesn't have to be fully event-driven if it seems that things go too complicated.

Comment: I see. From my understanding applying an event-driven architecture would rather increase complexity and not really reduce dependencies in the given basic example.

Comment: Event-based is good when (non-exhaustive list): things happen randomly and it's desirable to inform the consumer(s) and letting them do a small update, rather than full reload; you want to broadcast something to many consumers; you want to inform consumers that something has happened and let them decide what to do about it. Yes it adds complexity - but solves some complex problems well, it's a question of identifying the 'right tool for the job'.

Answer (score 2):

[Event storming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_storming#:%7E:text=Event%20storming%20is%20a%20workshop,notes%20on%20a%20wide%20wall.) is the first thing you need to do to identify domain events(a change in state in your system). For example, 'userCreated', 'userModified', 'locatinCreated', 'routeCreated', 'routeCompleted' etc. Then you can define topics that manage these events. Interested parties can consume these events by subscribing to published events(via topics/channel) and then act accordingly. Implementation of an event-driven architecture is often composed of loosely coupled microservices that communicate asynchronously through a message broker like Apache Kafka. Free [EDA book](https://assets.confluent.io/m/7a91acf41502a75e/original/20180328-EB-Confluent_Designing_Event_Driven_Systems.pdf) is an excellent resource to know most of the things in EDA.

[Tutorial: Even-driven-architecture pattern](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/advantages-of-an-event-driven-architecture/)
[image]

Comment: That means map-data-service would need to keep a record of "users who are allowed to add locations", to avoid having to ask user-service for authorization. Which means some of the role logic, as well as some of the user data have to exist in two places.

Comment: Service boundaries/ bounded contexts should be defined correctly to avoid data duplication and this where DDD comes is. In authorization, user/auth service will manage permission and those are shared in jwt tokens. Using an API gateway you can authorize the token with the issuer and you can perform the authorizations in service level based or roles and permissions.

Comment: This looks a lot like a workflow scenario: call taxi > allocate taxi > send location, meaning this necessarily have to be done sequentially each step need some context of the previous one (who called the taxi, where, who to send the location to etc). In that case I keep thinking that there should be a way to trace the whole chain. This would be easy to do in a tightly coupled application, but I wonder how to go around this issue using events.